# apply binary operation to all adjacent pairs

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a built-in or more efficient approach than using `Partition` to apply a binary operation to adjacent pairs of elements?  That is, is it reasonable to be using the following for a binary operation `f` and a possibly long list (here, just `{a,b,c}`) the following approach?

```
Map[f @@ # &, Partition[{a, b, c}, 2, 1]]
```

Related: will the result of this use of `Partition` ever actually be constructed in full, or are the pairs just generated on demand?  (And how can I anticipate the answer to this question?)

Comment: something like this? `f @@ list[[# ;; # + 1]] & /@ Range[Length[list] - 1]`

Comment: `l = {a, b, c};
Inner[f, Most@l, Rest@l, List]`

Comment: @belisariushassettled If I'm willing to risk the construciton of `Most` and `Rest`, I can just use `Thread`.  But that gets me back to my question of how I can know when such things will be constructed.

Comment: You can verify how Mathematica is calculating (more or less) by `Map[f @@ # &, Partition[{a, b, c}, 2, 1]] // Trace`

Comment: Regarding the second question, `Map` has no `Hold*` attributes so the full `Partition` will be evaluated before Map sees it. The pairs are not generated on demand.

Comment: ...actually, you can just do `f @@@ Partition[{a, b, c}, 2, 1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a packed numerical list it is both faster and less memory intensive to use `ListConvolve`:

```
list = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^7];
f = Plus;

AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[
  res1 = Map[f @@ # &, Partition[list, 2, 1]]]
(* {2.37724, 320005544} *)

AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[
  res2 = ListConvolve[{1, 1}, list, {-1, 1}, {}, Times, f]]
(* {0.290708, 80006000} *)

res1 == res2
(* True *)
```

Comment: While comparable in terms of memory compared to `ListConvolve`, ``Developer`PartitionMap`` takes about twice as long as `Map` on my machine.

Comment: Wonderful!  `PartitionMap` is exactly what I was looking for.  Presumably it will get faster ...   But I'm also very happy to learn about this use of `ListConvolve`.  I confess I had hopefully skimmed the documentation for it without discovering how to do this.